# Why does Auth0 reset Rails session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, auth0

I have a simple auth0 integration with a Rails application and I'm trying to persist the `account_id` in a session. I've noticed that if I use the local login, it correctly sets the session. If I use a social provider, it will remove the `userinfo` and the `account_id` in the session. Why and also how?

Interestingly enough, in another controller action, if I set the same key the session will persist.

```
class Auth0Controller < ApplicationController
  def callback
    session[:userinfo] = request.env['omniauth.auth']

    account_attributes = session.dig :userinfo, :extra, :raw_info

    result = Accounts::Create.(params: account_attributes)

    session[:account_id] = result[:model].uuid

    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def failure
    @error_msg = request.params['message']
  end
end
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
#  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

development.rb

```
...
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end
```

I've tried:

- using multiple browsers
- using different Oauth providers (Facebook and LinkedIn)
- different session store `config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'my_session'`

My best guess now is that this has something to do with the auth0 callback controller specifically. I've set up the apps and those successfully log in users, but they do not persist the `userinfo` in the session. I've copied the code directly from the sample app and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around which is just to store that data in an encrypted cookie.

```
cookies.encrypted[:account_id] = result[:model].uuid
```

I don't love it but it works.